# VMware: this host is virtualization-capable but virtualization is not enabled

Tags: bios, vt-x

I have a Dell E6400 - running Windows 7. I am using VMware Workstation 6.5 - trying to create a Debian VM. Upon trying to install the 64-bit version of it, it said:

> this host is vt-capable but vt is not enabled

I've now enabled virtualization in my BIOS, restarted (cold restart - even pulled the battery out!) But it still says it's not enabled.

I've updated to the latest BIOS, tried again - BIOS said it's enabled, VMware says it's not!

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a small utility that will tell you if you are ready for 64-bit VMware called [SecurAble](http://www.grc.com/securable.htm). With both texts saying YES, you should be set for 64-bit.

If it still won't work, then try and post the exact computer model and motherboard type, someone might lead you on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

You need to switch off the execution disable bit too.
I can't tell where on your BIOS that option is. Most likely under some security tab or submenu.